# How to Add Multiple Child Row Data together with Parent Row in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel-6

I've been trying to work the adding of multiple data through blade. In my blade form, I'm using the clone, adding rows. For example, one requisition has many items.

My blade view
[image]

Blade View Code

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="{{ route("requisition.store") }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required" for="purpose">Purpose</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="purpose" id="purpose" required>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required" for="requisition_date">Date</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="date" name="requisition_date" id="requisition_date" required>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="required" for="requested_by">Released By</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="requested_by" id="requested_by" required>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Qty</th>    
                    <th>Unit</th>    
                    <th>Description</th>   
                    <th>
                        <a href="#" class="addRow"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>    
                    </th> 
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="rows[0][qty]" class="form-control quantity" required>  
                    </td>    
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="rows[0][unit]" class="form-control" required>  
                    </td>    
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="rows[0][description]" class="form-control" required>  
                    </td> 
                    <td>

                    </td>   
                </tr> 
            </tbody>    
        </table>



        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Script code for cloning

```
function addRow()
{
    var tr = '<tr>'+
    '<td><input type="number" name="rows[0][qty]" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="rows[0][unit]" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
    '<td><input type="text" name="rows[0][description]" class="form-control quantity"></td>'+
    '<td><a class="btn btn-danger remove"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></a></td>'+
    '</tr>';
    $('tbody').append(tr);
  }
```

And my store controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $requisition = Requisition::create([
            'purpose' => $request->input('purpose'),
            'requisition_date' => $request->input('requisition_date'),
            'requested_by' => $request->input('requested_by')
        ]);  

        $rows = $request->input('rows');

        foreach ($rows as $row)
        {
            $items[] = [
                'requisition_id' => $requisition->id,
                'qty' => $row['qty'],
                'unit' => $row['unit'],
                'description' => $row['description']
            ];
        }

        RequisitionItem::insert($items);
```

}

My problem in my store controller code is that it is only add one item instead of more than one.
My models:
Requisition table = 'id', 'purpose', 'requisition_date', 'requested_by', 'requisition_date'
RequisitionItem table =  'id', 'requisition_id', 'qty', 'unit', 'description'

dd($rows) results

[image]

Comment: plz `dd($rows)` and post it.

Comment: I post the results of dd($rows)

Comment: You have called $request->input('rows'); but I can not see any input name as "rows" In your HTML

Comment: @BossPogs your $rows only have one row, plz check your js code, did it really add more rows to request?

Comment: I edit my question and show my js code if I'm doing it right for the cloning. I just want to check it out if it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use your append inputs and blade inputs both like this...

```
name="qty[]"
```

Instead of

```
name="rows[0][qty]"
```

And in controller loop through one field that will always be added. For example;

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($request->qty); $i++)
    {
        RequisitionItem::insert([
            'requisition_id' => $requisition->id,
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'unit' => $request->unit[$i],
            'description' => $request->description[$i]
        ]);
    }
```

You can also follow this procedure as well,

```
  for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($request->qty); $i++)
    {
        $items[] = [
            'requisition_id' => $requisition->id,
            'qty' => $request->qty[$i],
            'unit' => $request->unit[$i],
            'description' => $request->description[$i]
        ];
    }

  RequisitionItem::insert($items);
```